# refactoring ruby: want to pass attribute name into a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a DataPoint model where I have three methods that do the same thing, just on different fields in the data_points database.

```
def self.currently_employed(data_points)
    data_points.where(currently_employed: true).count / data_points.count.to_f * 100
end

def self.undergrad_degree(data_points)
    data_points.where(undergrad_degree: true).count / data_points.count.to_f * 100
end

def self.grad_degree(data_points)
    data_points.where(grad_degree: true).count / data_points.count.to_f * 100
end
```

I think I should be able to refactor this to accept which column to perform the calculation on as a parameter, but much time on the internet / trying stuff out hasn't yielded results.

Could someone please advise me on whether / how I could refactor this to a single method?

In case it affects the answer: the data_points argument is a subset of DataPoint.all specified by the User - i.e. User types in what age, years work experience, etc. they want to see results for (age & years_work_experience are DataPoint attributes), and then I want to show summary stats for that subset.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the attribute is really just a key in a hash.

```
data_points.where(currently_employed: true)
```

Is equivalent to

```
data_points.where({:currently_employed => true})
```

With this in mind, it's easy to refactor these methods into one:

```
def self.percent_with_attribute(data_points, attribute)
    data_points.where(attribute => true).count / data_points.count.to_f * 100
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string interpolation here.

```
def self.status(data_points, key)
  data_points.where("#{key}": true).count / data_points.count.to_f * 100
end
```

How it differs from @Ajedi32's answer is only in that the `key` here will be converted to a `Symbol`, instead of a plain `String`.

Comment: To clarify, my answer only passes the attribute as a string if the attribute argument given to `percent_with_attribute` was already a string. If the attribute argument was a symbol, it will be passed as a symbol. This answer converts the argument to a symbol regardless of whether it was passed as a string, symbol, or any other object that responds to `to_s`. In practice, there's probably not any real significant difference between these two approaches, since AFAIK Rails treats string and symbol keys identically.

Comment: That's correct, but I thought I would provide the alternative solution as well.

Comment: No. There isn't. Except the syntax for the hash will change to `key.to_sym => true`.